# Modern books on discrete (finite difference) calculus?

Tags: discrete-calculus

I'm having a hard time finding "modern" mathematics textbooks on discrete calculus. Reference [1] has some good material but its audience are mostly computer scientists.

[1] Knuth, D. E., Graham, R. L., Patashnik, O. (1994). Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science. Germany: Addison-Wesley.

Comment: What do you mean by "discrete calculus" ? Calculus of [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) ?

Comment: Yes. Added to the title.

Comment: Is "An Introduction to the Calculus of Finite Differences and Difference Equations"
by Kenneth S. Miller still edited (around 1960...) ?

Comment: Concrete Mathematics is still accessible for a math person if you ignore the CS material. I paid no attention to discussions on hashing and the like when I did.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pdf https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4hdqqixming8ls/EDC.pdf. It is called Elementary Discrete Calculus.